# How to put reference to variable instead of variable value into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers

In swift how do I put a pointer into an array?

I have several arrays, in all of them I make reference to a variable and when I change it I need it to update in all the other arrays.

Edit:
Basically i have an array

```
var ExampleArray     : NSMutableArray = [
    0,
    "TestString",
    ["*"],
    9,
]
```

What i want to do is add a pointer to the array so it would be like

```
var ExampleArray     : NSMutableArray = [
    0,
    "TestString",
    ["*"],
    9,
    //Pointer Here
]
```

The pointer is to a string that features in many arrays, if update its value in one array i want it to update in all the arrays

How do i declare this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It literally can't get any simpler than this:

```
var value: Int = 0
var array: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>] = []

withUnsafeMutablePointer(&value, array.append)
```

But maybe you want to store multiple types, in which case the following should suffice:

```
var value: Int = 0
var array: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>] = []

public func getVoidPointer<T>(inout x: T) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
{
    return withUnsafeMutablePointer(&x, { UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>($0) })
}

array.append(getVoidPointer(&value))
```

Comment: This answer is correct enough.  It's worth noting though that the this will only accept pointers to `Int` (obviously).  If we use `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, we can accept pointers to any type.  +1 though.

Comment: @nhgrif: Well noted. I've updated my answer to reflect your observations.

Comment: I've updated my question, i know its really obvious and I'm certainly over thinking it